# android-How to use dark theme for dialog on api8+

Tags: android, android-theme

this is the dialog I have right now :

[image]

as you can see, it's white . How can I use dark theme for this dialog ? I want to make it dark . 
I'm using appcompact and I want it to work on api+8 .

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to simply link to a library, but that's the only way I know to make that work on such old API levels.

[library:AlertDialogPro@github](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro) (API 7+)

```
<style name="YourAppTheme">
    <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialogPro.Material</item>
</style>
```

A README and a demo application is included.